# Information entered into php form remains there until submitted

Tags: php, forms

I have a form and I would like to have any information someone enters into it remain there until they have sent the information or closed the website.

I have a form that I been placed into different pages using php include. When I move to each page that has this form I want the information already entered from the other pages to still be there. Is this possible?

I can get the information to remain there if I reload the page using the following code:

```
$_SESSION['varname'] = $_POST['varname'];
```

but I can't get the information to remain there is I go to a different page and come back.

Thanks

Comment: Are you including the `session_start();` on all of your pages?

Comment: Yes I have it included in all my pages

Answer (score 0):

Set SESSION using Ajax on input change, it's just an idea;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('input').change(function(){
     var data = $('this').val();
     var url = 'setsessionhere.php';
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: data
     });
  });
</script>
```

and Put your session variable on your input value:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['varname']; ?>"/>
```

Hopely you understand.

Comment: I get an error.... 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/squareli/public_html/order_form.php on line 5. Line 5 is the first line of your code

Comment: Sorry, It's Jquery. You do know Jquery, don't you?

Comment: No not to familiar with it. Haven't been doing coding for a few years now, just getting back into the swing of things with this project. I have a value already, can I add a second one? I removed mine for the moment to see if this would work and the only thing that happens is "echo Array{'varname'}" shows up in the input box when I load the page.